# Find maximum according to a parameter

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic, warning-messages

I am new to *Mathematica*. I want to find the maximum of the functions:

```
FindMaximum[
 (1 + y)^2/((1 + y)^2 + (1 + x)^2)* 5 - y - (1/((1 + x)^2 + 1))*5 && 0 < y < 2 
, y]
```

So I want to find the maximum of above function, with y in the range 0 to 2, taking $x$ as a parameter. However it showed the error

> ```
> FindMaximum::nrnum: 
> The function value 1. +(5 (1+x)^2)/(1+(1+x)^2)-(5 (2. +x)^2)/(1+(2. +x)^2)
> is not a real number at {y} = {1.}
> ```

**How can I fix this?**

It only works if I input a certain value for $x$ (such as `x=1`).

Thank you all so much!

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Did any of the answers fulfill your question?  If the answers do give what you asked for, there are **[things to for you to do](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. If it didn't then you should [edit] your question and explain in more detail what you asked. For follow-up needs ask a new question and link to this one. Stay vigilant for a day or two, better approaches may come later and other users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and a day or two before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an analytical solution then use [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html)

```
ClearAll[expr, max, sol, x, y];
expr = (1 + y)^2/((1 + y)^2 + (1 + x)^2)*5 - y - (1/((1 + x)^2 + 1))*5;

max = Simplify[
   Maximize[
    {expr, 0 < y < 2}
    , y
    ]
   ];
```

The solution is not compact.

```
sol = Assuming[
   0 < y < 2,
   Simplify[expr /. Last@max]
   ];

Plot[
 sol
 , {x, -5, 5}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 ]
```

[image]

---

If you are looking for a numerical minimization, then you got your syntax wrong and have to define all symbols either as values or minimizing variables.

```
FindMaximum[
{
 (1+y)^2/((1+y)^2+(1+x)^2)*5-y-(1/((1+x)^2+1))*5
 , 0<y<2
}, {x,y}]
(* {0.675445,{x->0.470469,y->1.16228}} *)
```

or

```
With[
{x=1},
FindMaximum[
 {
  (1+y)^2/((1+y)^2+(1+x)^2)*5-y-(1/((1+x)^2+1))*5
  , 0<y<2
 }
, {y}
]]
(* {0.550873,{y->1.41368}} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe you misunderstood my question. What I meant is that I want to take x as a parameter, not a variable. So I want to find maximum of y, keeping x constant as some number

Comment: @user66418 thanks for clarifying. I hope my answer now does address your need. If it does, probably we should delete the obsolete comments.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that's what I looked for. However the solution looks very messy, since I need to plot y ( as expression of x) into another function, and maximize again. Is there any way?

Comment: The `sol` that I offer does what you ask in your question. It's *messy* by nature, not as a consequence of the method. If you need to do now something different, like maximizing again, you should ask another question with the new requirements, and people will be happy to answer there.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical solution using `NMaximize`

```
maxi[x_?NumericQ] :=NMaximize[{(1 + y)^2/((1 + y)^2 + (1 + x)^2)*5 -y - (1/((1 + x)^2 + 1))*5, 0 < y < 2}, y][[1]]

Plot[maxi [x], {x, -1, 3}] (* takes some time... *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this numerically in cases where [`Maximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize) is unable to work symbolically. Here is your function:

```
expr = (1 + y)^2/((1 + y)^2 + (1 + x)^2)* 5 - y - (1/((1 + x)^2 + 1))*5 /. y -> y[x];
expr //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{5 (y(x)+1)^2}{(y(x)+1)^2+(x+1)^2}-y(x)-\frac{5}{(x+1)^2+1}$

where I introduced an `x` dependence in the variable `y`. Then, the following [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) call finds an [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction) result for the maximum function:

```
m = NDSolveValue[
    {
    D[D[expr, y[x]] == 0, x],
    z[x] == expr,
    y[0] == NArgMax[{expr /. x->0, 0 < y[0] < 2}, y[0]]
    },
    z,
    {x, 0, 2}
];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[m[t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Note that this approach can break down when different branches cross, or when boundary conditions (0 < y < 2) interfere.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assuming[Element[x, Reals], 
  Maximize[{(1 + y)^2/((1 + y)^2 + (1 + x)^2)*5 - y - (1/((1 + x)^2 + 1))*5, 0 < y < 2}, y]]
```